# JavaScript Design Patterns with Meteor

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, meteor, meteorite

I have a Meteor project that is starting to get out of hand with about 800 lines of code. I set out today to modularize and clean things up a bit and things are looking good, but I'm getting some errors that I don't know the best way how to deal with.

Here's a prime example.

I am using d3 to create a force layout (this question isnt specific to d3). I instantiate some variables and most notably

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
```

in a file

```
/client/views/force/forceLayout.js
```

I made a bunch of controls for this force layout and put them in their own .html and .js files. Heres an example

```
initChargeSlider = function() {
    d3.select("#charge-slider")
        .call(d3.slider()
            .min(-301)
            .max(-1)
            .step(5)
            .value(Session.get("charge"))
            .on("slide", function(evt, value) {
                Session.set("charge", value);
                // force.stop();
                force = force.charge(value);
                force.start();
            }));
}

Template.charge.rendered = function() {
    initChargeSlider();
};
```

in file

```
/client/views/force/controls/sliders/charge.js
```

Due to Meteor loading deeper directories first, I get an error at `force = force.charge(value)` because `forceLayout.js` hasn't instantiated `force` yet.

I'm curious what is the most best way of dealing with this. Moving the files around and loading order is just reversing all the modularizing I just did. I think a singleton or an object or monad may be in order but I'm not sure which or why. I would appreciate an explanation of how to go about fixing these errors.

Thanks

Chet

Comment: That is a bit strange indeed. I was under the impression that `rendered` callback will only be called when all the files have been fetched and `Meteor.startup` call has been made. Are you sure that you are not prematurely calling `initChargeSlider` from somewhere which should be inside `Meteor.startup`?

Comment: Just did a Find in Files and those are the only two places `initChargeSlider` shows up.

Comment: I think the issue is the function is instantiated with a scope of before force is instantiated -- not sure how that all works but...

Comment: If you disable the call in the rendered function, then does `window.force` get defined at all?

Comment: I added a `console.log(force);` in `initChargeSlider` and I get the same error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: force is not defined`.

Comment: `console.log` on an undefined value does not throw an error (unless "use strict" is defined on a function, I think). You should have seen a `undefined` on the console if it had executed. Did you see it?

Comment: OK. When I have the console.log I get this fatal error: `Exception from Deps afterFlush function: ReferenceError: force is not defined`. If I dont have the console.log, I dont get an error til I move the slider in which I get the `Uncaught ReferenceError: force is not defined`. Sorry about the confusion there.

Comment: `window.force` is undefined along with `force`. However, if I put a `console.log(force)` statement in forceLayout.js, I get force printed out -- perhaps I'm get getting the scope all wrong.

Comment: Then there probably is an `"use strict"` lurking in there somewhere and the `force` variable is being assigned in the incorrect scope. Try defining it explicitly as global by saying `window.force = d3.layout.force()`.

Comment: OK. assigning to window.force worked -- but isn't that taboo?

Comment: If a global variable is what is desired, then it is best to be explicit about it.

Comment: This seems related but I have no idea what `use strict` is: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1380

Comment: In meteor, variables are scoped to the files in which they are defined if you use the var keyword. You have to omit the var keyword to export it to the global scope and be able to use "force" in your template code. See the docs : http://docs.meteor.com/#namespacing

Comment: leavin off var works as well -- i actually like that better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor before `0.6.5` run files without wrapping them inside a function wrapper `(function() { /* your code */ })()`.

This behavior is still followed if you place your files in `client/compatibility` folder:

> Some JavaScript libraries only work when placed in the
>   client/compatibility subdirectory. Files in this directory are
>   executed without being wrapped in a new variable scope. This means
>   that each top-level var defines a global variable. In addition, these
>   files are executed before other client-side JavaScript files.

Now, Meteor is more unforgiving of global variables and now one needs to be explicit about declaring them. Hence,

```
window.force = d3.layout.force()
```

or even

```
this.force = d3.layout.force(); // this === window in global context.
```

would solve the problem.

Comment: @saimeunt is right as well -- simply leaving off var will work